# journalctl stops logging systemd service logs with systemd_unit field

Tags: systemd, systemd-journald

This is a question about journalctl and how systemd log entries are produced.
My OS is RHEL8.

I've got a systemd service setup to run kubelet as a systemd service, and I would like to use journalctl to tail the logs using the unit flag with "journalctl -u kubelet".

When I initially start the systemd service, I can see kubelet logs show up in /var/log/messages and I can also filter them using "journalctl -u kubelet".  However, very shortly after the service is started, journalctl goes quiet when filtering with "-u kubelet", yet kubelet logs continue to be dumped into /var/log/messages.  If I filter journalctl with "journalctl --identifier kubelet" instead of the "-u kubelet" I do see all the logs that are in /var/log/messages.

Using "-o json-pretty", I can see that the initial logs produced by the kubelet process have journald log entries with:

```
    "_SYSTEMD_CGROUP" : "/system.slice/kubelet.service",
    "_SYSTEMD_INVOCATION_ID" : "b422558179854d55a44d0ea6f7240828",
    "_SYSTEMD_SLICE" : "system.slice",
    "_SYSTEMD_UNIT" : "kubelet.service",
```

Logs produced shortly after starting the service is started seem to drop the unit property, and look like:

```
    "_SYSTEMD_CGROUP" : "/systemd/system.slice",
    "_SYSTEMD_INVOCATION_ID" : "b422558179854d55a44d0ea6f7240828",
    "_SYSTEMD_SLICE" : "-.slice",
```

I think the fact that the logs start being produced without the "_SYSTEMD_UNIT" property indicates why filtering them with "-u" stops working, but I'd like to know why my service initially starts producing logs with the unit property, and then stops.  Any clues would be appreciated.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or, in this case, https://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this had more to do with kubelet configuration than it did journald configuration.  kubelet needed to designate the correct cgroup in the kubeletCgroups config.